# openni kinect depth value

Tags: ros, openni, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the openni SimpleViewer, the depth value is 10000 max. Can somebody tell me what's the value stands for? Why it's not 2047 max ? I find that there is an SampleConfig.xml, how to configure my kinect?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9884/openni-kinect-depth-value/) by [Bruce](https://answers.ros.org/users/224/bruce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, the value of 10000 is the maximum depth in millimeters. Thats not a software limit, but a limit given by the hardware. Also the value is somewhere given in the OpenNI/PS-Engine libraries.
As "Mac" mentioned, the point clouds published by the node is already in meters in the corresponding coordinate frame.

-Suat

---

Originally posted by [Suat Gedikli](https://answers.ros.org/users/275/suat-gedikli/) with karma: 91 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0